# How to change words in a list to upper/lower case using range - Python

Tags: python, list, range, uppercase, lowercase

One part of my assignment is to get user input, convert that into a list, then depending on the number of characters in each word, change to upper/lower case accordingly. I have been told I have to use range, which is the part I am struggling with. This is my latest attempt but it's not working. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
poem = input("Enter a poem, verse or saying: ")
words_list = poem.split()
list_len = len(words_list)
for word in range(0,list_len):
    if len(words_list[word]) < 4:
        word = word.lower()
    elif len(words_list[word]) > 6:
        word = words.upper()
```

Comment: It isn't. `word` is the integer value of the `range`. What should the output be? Are you trying to modify `word_list` and return that list?

Comment: You have it right in part of your code that `words_list[word]` is the actual word, a string. Keep using that everywhere. You also need to assign to that index, i.e. `words_list[word] = ...`. Assigning to a local variable will not change the list.

Comment: Name your variables to reflect what they are: for instance, use `word` for a word, and `wdx` for the indice of a word in the list of words... that will help you understand the confusion

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this question, but have you had a look at the documentation of the range function in python? Check [this tutorial](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) and play around with the range function instead of asking for a solution to your assignment as it will help you more in understanding.

Comment: Hi Thomas - yes I spent ages trying to look this up myself but I just couldn't quite figure it out. The amendment to the code to get it working was so simple but I'd been staring at it so long I just couldn't see it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small modification to your original code. Since you want to convert to upper/lower case, you also want to probably save the output. You can alternatively use a new list to save your output rather than replacing the values in the original list `words_list`

```
for word in range(0,list_len):
    if len(words_list[word]) < 4:
        words_list[word] = words_list[word].lower()
    elif len(words_list[word]) > 6:
        words_list[word] = words_list[word].upper()

print(words_list)
```

**Output**

```
Enter a poem, verse or saying: My name is bazingaa
['my', 'name', 'is', 'BAZINGAA']
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Seemed so obvious seeing it there but just couldn't work it out!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
poem = input("Enter a poem, verse or saying: ")
words_list = poem.split()
out = ""
for word in words_list:
    if len(word) < 4:
        word = word.lower()
    elif len(word) > 6:
        word = word.upper()
    out += " " + word
print(out)
```

Removed uneeded "list_len" variable, looped in "words_list" and checking length of "word". And concentrate output with "out" variable. For output there could be better techniques, I just did an easy one.

Comment: I think the requirement is to use range

Answer (score 0):

```
poem = input("Enter a poem, verse or saying: ")
words_list = poem.split()
list_len = len(words_list)

# word is not a word here, it was an integer
# by a convention we use 'i' for the iterator here
for i in range(0,list_len):
    # here we assign an actual 'word' to the word variable
    word = words_list[i]
    if len(word) < 4:
        # therefore you couldn't use .lower() or .upper() on the integer
        word = word.lower()
    elif len(word) > 6:
        word = word.upper()
```

Use a proper IDE for coding like PyCharm. It would alert you about all the mistakes you've made.

That will work if you really need to use range, but you still need to figure out printing / returning the value.

If you don't know what's going on just put some `print`s wherever you need. You would figure it out by yourself if you put prints in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a several problems. The `word` is the value of the iterator and so it is an integer. You can't use the functions `upper` and `lower` on integer. However, you can solve it in an easier way:

```
poem = input("Enter a poem, verse or saying: ")
words_list = poem.split()
for i in range(0,len(words_list)):
    word = words_list[i]
    word = word.lower() if len(word) < 4 else word
    if len(word) > 6:word = word.upper()
    print(word)
```

On executing the above code:

```
Enter a poem, verse or saying: Programming in Python is great
PROGRAMMING
in
Python
is
great
```

You can also make its function which returns a list (also uses `range`):

```
def get(string):
    words_list = string.split()
    output = []
    for i in range(0,len(words_list)):
        word = words_list[i]
        word = word.lower() if len(word) < 4 else word
        if len(word) > 6:word = word.upper()
        output.append(word)
    return output

print(get(input("Enter a poem, verse or saying: ")))
```

Testing:

```
Enter a poem, verse or saying: Programming in Python is great
['PROGRAMMING', 'in', 'Python', 'is', 'great']
```